# While clicking on one button I am getting the exception as - "org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.request.InvalidUrlException"

Tags: java

At the client side when they select a country from the dropdown and then they will be clicking on one button who loads the data from DB they are getting the below exception after some time:

```
2019-08-29 09:46:26,838 [ajp-8005-8] ERROR UserName[dcheong] org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.logRuntimeException(RequestCycle.java:1531) - org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: After 1 minute the Pagemap null is still locked by: Thread[ajp-8005-6,5,main], giving up trying to get the page for path: 2:mainform:intermediaryButton
org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.request.InvalidUrlException: org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: After 1 minute the Pagemap null is still locked by: Thread[ajp-8005-6,5,main], giving up trying to get the page for path: 2:mainform:intermediaryButton
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebRequestCycleProcessor.resolve(WebRequestCycleProcessor.java:262)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1312)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1438)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:546)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:486)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:319)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.tekinsure.apps.common.profile.AbstractUserProfileServicesFilter.doFilter(AbstractUserProfileServicesFilter.java:215)
    at com.tekinsure.apps.common.profile.AbstractUserProfileServicesFilter.doFilter(AbstractUserProfileServicesFilter.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.tekinsure.apps.common.filter.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:60)
    at com.tekinsure.apps.common.filter.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.tekinsure.apps.common.ognl.OgnlCleanupFilter.doFilter(OgnlCleanupFilter.java:22)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.tekinsure.session.filter.SessionCleanupFilter.doFilter(SessionCleanupFilter.java:31)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.tekinsure.acl.filter.ACLCleanupFilter.doFilter(ACLCleanupFilter.java:31)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.tekinsure.tpass.TPassForwardFilter.doFilter(TPassForwardFilter.java:68)
    at com.tekinsure.tpass.TPassForwardFilter.doFilter(TPassForwardFilter.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.tekinsure.workbench.agent.filter.RequestDumpFilter.doFilter(RequestDumpFilter.java:36)
    at com.tekinsure.workbench.agent.filter.RequestDumpFilter.doFilter(RequestDumpFilter.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.tekinsure.workbench.agent.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:27)
    at com.tekinsure.workbench.agent.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:427)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpAprProtocol.java:384)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1584)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

They have restarted the JVM and tomcat servers but still facing the same issue for an only a single country.

Comment: post your work code

Comment: Welcome to SO community. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask